# Getting AccessViolationException when P/Invoking function from a C++/Win32 DLL

Tags: c++, vb.net, pinvoke, dllimport, huffman-code

I'm trying to P/Invoke a function from a C++/Win32 dll, but whenever I call it I get the following error:

```
System.AccessViolationException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.StubHelpers.MngdNativeArrayMarshaler.ConvertContentsToManaged(IntPtr pMarshalState, Object& pManagedHome, IntPtr pNativeHome)
  InnerException: (Nothing)
```

With the call stack showing (using unmanaged debugging):

`ZaRCon.exe!ZaRCon.Huffman.Encode(Byte() Array) Line 50 + 0x15 bytes`

It appears to be a problem with the parameters *(due to the `MngdNativeArrayMarshaler.ConvertContentsToManaged()` call)*. I have tried changing the parameters' declaration but with no success. In the beginning I had trouble converting them, so after some research on other Stack Overflow questions I came up with the below.

**C++ function declaration:**

```cpp
void __declspec(dllexport) HUFFMAN_Encode( unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out, int inlen, int *outlen );
```

**VB.NET P/Invoke:**

```vb
<DllImport("HuffmanNative.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Private Shared Sub HUFFMAN_Encode(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> [in] As Byte(), _
                                   <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> ByRef [out] As Byte(), _
                                    ByVal inlen As Integer, ByRef outlen As Integer)
End Sub
```

**How I call it:**

```vb
Public Shared Function Encode(ByVal Array As Byte()) As Byte()
    Dim Output As Byte() = New Byte(4096 - 1) {}
    Dim OutputLength As Integer = 0
    HUFFMAN_Encode(Array, Output, Array.Length, OutputLength) 'The error occurs on this line.
    Return Output
End Function
```

The C++ function is used to encode data sent over network using a special version of the Huffman algorithm.

I'm not sure if the error is thrown at the moment of calling the function... After creating a test version in C# (which gave me various very different results) I was able to get a line in the source code, *however I'm not sure if it's the same error thrown when using VB.NET*:

```cpp
void HUFFMAN_Encode( unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out, int inlen, int *outlen )
{
    int i,j,bitat;
    unsigned int t;
    bitat=0;
    for (i=0;i<inlen;i++)
    {
        t=HuffLookup[in[i]].bits;
        for (j=0;j<HuffLookup[in[i]].len;j++)
        {
            huffman_PutBit(out+1,bitat+HuffLookup[in[i]].len-j-1,t&1);
            t>>=1;
        }
        bitat+=HuffLookup[in[i]].len;
    }
    *outlen=1+(bitat+7)/8;
    *out=8*((*outlen)-1)-bitat; //<-- The error I got when using C# was thrown here.
    if(*outlen >= inlen+1)
    {
        *out=0xff;
        memcpy(out+1,in,inlen);
        *outlen=inlen+1;
    }
}
```

So my guess is that the byte arrays that I send to the function isn't converted properly to the native `unsigned char` pointer array. But if that is the case, how should the P/Invoke be performed? And if that is not the case, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `ByRef` from the second argument and the p/invoke declaration matches the native code.

There is also little point specifying `CharSet` when there is no text. The `MarshalAs` attributes are also unnecessary.

Comment: Wow, it works! I thought I had already tried making the second argument `ByVal`. Thanks alot!